# Load local html files from applications's document directory swift wkwebview

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am trying to load a local html file which is downloaded to my application with wkwebview. Along with this html file i am downloading two js files, they are referenced inside the html file.

But what ever i do, they are not loading in wkwebview

```
 @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet var act: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Adding webView content
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self


let fm = FileManager.default
    let docsurl = try! fm.url(for:.documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    let myurl = docsurl.appendingPathComponent("index.html")
    print("my url = ",myurl )
// myurl prints file///var/some directories/index.html
let request = URLRequest(url: myurl!)
            webView.load(request)
}
```

My html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html> 
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>This is a heading</h2>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<button>Click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

But it is not loading on the screen from safari(Develop/) i can see that `An error occured trying to load the resource`, page is coming as about:blank

Comment: What does `myurl ` print? How are you using `WKWebView` here?

Comment: `But it is not loading on the screen from safari(Develop/)` What does it mean? Safari is en external browser. Do you mean by `WebView` only and not the Safari?

Comment: There is no issue with this code `let request = URLRequest(url: myurl)
        self.webView.load(request)`. You need to check if file exists on same url by making Data object from this url.

Comment: @TheTiger, yes , its working fine in my simulator, but not working in iPhone(real device)

Comment: Your acceptance rate is 0. You haven't accepted any one of answer to your all questions. This is not good.

Answer (score 2):

**swift 4.2**

```
 //load HTML
let bundle = Bundle.main
var path = bundle.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html")
var html = ""
do {
    try html = String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: .utf8)
} catch {
//ERROR
}
let urlstr = "http://website.com"
webViewWK.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: URL(string: urlstr)!)
```

Answer (score 2):

`URLRequest` is basically made for live url. For system file just load the `URL`. You need to use below method and it will work:

```
/*! @abstract Navigates to the requested file URL on the filesystem.
     @param URL The file URL to which to navigate.
     @param readAccessURL The URL to allow read access to.
     @discussion If readAccessURL references a single file, only that file may be loaded by WebKit.
     If readAccessURL references a directory, files inside that file may be loaded by WebKit.
     @result A new navigation for the given file URL.
     */
    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    open func loadFileURL(_ URL: URL, allowingReadAccessTo readAccessURL: URL) -> WKNavigation?
```

So that:

```
self.webView.loadFileURL(myurl, allowingReadAccessTo: myurl)
```